# how to change the format of a field when using parse to select fields in sumologic

Tags: parsing, format, field, transfer, sumologic

I am totally new to sumologic platform. I am trying to select fields from the log data. The simple code is:

```
| parse "transactionNumber=*|" as transactionNumber
| parse "message=*|" as message
```

My transaction number is a very long numbers, such as 123456789987654321. So, when I 'Export(Display Fields)' to save the result to csv file, it will be automatically transfer to scientific notation such as 123e+15.

So, how to change the format, let's say from number to character, so that I can get the real numbers in csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simple way is save the file as txt, instead of csv.
But this is not related to sumo logic programming. So I think this is not a very "descent" way.